# Remove Password from Excel File -- Without having to Install Excel on my servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I need to remove the password protection from an uploaded excel file. I have been doing this directly with the Excel assemblies (ASP.NET/C#) and then I tried with the [ooxmlcrypto](http://code.google.com/p/ooxmlcrypto/), both worked, but the problem is that I can not deploy either of those solution because of the dependencies.

I mean, my sysadmin does not want us installing Excel on the server and, as I have been searching for some alternatives, I can not find one.

My question is: is there a way to put the necessary dlls in the server without installing Excel or the Office suite?

I found this: [Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&DisplayLang=en) but still, it requires a Microsoft Office Product.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Excel file formats do you want to support?

Comment: I just want to support Office 2007 and beyond

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the problem the wrong way. If you can't use Excel, then don't process Excel. Trying to reverse-engineer Excel is not the road you want to go down. Get your clients to use another format. For security, use an open encryption standard such as zipping the files. Also, spreadsheets are a terrible format for processing, because users will always find new ways of mangling the layout. They will submit dates as strings, or add a new column, etc. You will be forever making small changes to idiot-proof your code. Insist on something unambiguous, like csv

Comment: Very good answer, getting users to submit data in Excel is a nightmare. Where I work we employ a data import process for our core product, which allows users to edit data in Excel, but then we get them to set a range and export it as a DBF file. Still not pretty, but it allows us to kind of enforce some structure to the data.

Comment: -1: If you have to support managing Excel files on the server because the customer needs that, then that's how it is. Don't tell your customer "you have to change your requirement because I don't have a straightforward solution". There are many reasons why people want/need to work with Excel, and it's not simple at all just to get rid of it.

Comment: Of course you don't tell your customer how things will be - you make them a partner in the decision, but you try to think outside of the box and suggest other solutions. If Excel is mandatory, so be it, but reconsidering the need for Excel (much as I do love Excel) is an excellent example of rethinking the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party component to remove the Excel password.

For example:
[SmartXLS for .Net](http://www.smartxls.com) can read/write Excel97-2003 xls file and Excel2007 xlsx file with the password to encrypt/decrypt it.